# Swift - Update/Refresh Label that Displays Time

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a label which displays the current time in 12-hour format.

But, it does not update/refresh the time every time the minute/hour changes.

I need it to automatically change the label to the current time when the time changes.

Answer (score 13):

Swift 3 Solution

```
class ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    var timer: Timer?

    let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let tmpFormatter = DateFormatter()
        tmpFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        return tmpFormatter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(self.getTimeOfDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func getTimeOfDate() {
        var curDate = Date()

        timeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: curDate)
    }

}
```

Comment: @reecefox check my answer

Comment: Please use lower case names for variables, constants, properties and cases.

Comment: Is it necessary to set timer to nil after call `invalidate()`?

Comment: @GaneshKumar but doesn't `invalidate()` free memory already? Is there any reason to call `timer = nil` after `invalidate()`? I don't think you're obliged to nullify Timer instance under ARC.

Comment: sorry.. i mis understood it.. it doesnt need to be added

Comment: newbie here. Xcode says `NSTimer` should be renamed `Timer`. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: This is not very good. It starts in `viewDidLoad` and ends in `viewWillDisappear`. This means it will stop when you navigate or press the home-button, and won't restart when you get back in there. If using `viewWillDisappear` you should use `viewWillAppear` to start it. Or use `deinit` if using `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace following code with your ViewController code then connect IBOutlet to `showTimeLbl`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var showTimeLbl: UILabel!
    var timeCount:Int = 0
    var timer:Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if(timer != nil)
        {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerDidFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

    }

    func timerDidFire()
    {
        timeCount += 1

        showTimeLbl.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", timeCount/3600,(timeCount/60)%60,timeCount%60) as String
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: pretty sure swift has been updated thousands of times since that was posted, hence why I asked, because every other one is outdated.

Comment: @reecefox please check i have updated my answers in swift 3.0